# How to return csv values from a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have `List<item>` containing an items collections of name, years and values as follows

```
Names   years  Values
=====   =====  =====
Smith   2010   777
Smith   2011   999
Jones   2007   01
Jones   2008   03
Jones   2009   05
Jones   2010   06
Jones   2011   09
```

I want to write a LINQ query that returns me a a string of CSV values with the "name" followed by "values" for each year beginning with the earliest year (in this case its 2007) and if the "years" data is missing/absent (in this case Smith does not have any values for years 2007,2008,2009) then substitute the result with 0

As follows:

```
Results:
Smith,0,0,0,777,999
Jones,01,03,05,06,09
```

Comment: There is no delimiter between first and second column in your sample output. That doesn't look like CSV.

Comment: And what does `Item` look like? Hard to write (pseudo) code this way.

Comment: item contains 3 things item.names, item.years and item.value

Comment: what I a looking for is how to substitute 0 for values that so not exists?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to format the examples properly. You really love pain, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted a Linq solution so here it is:

```
list
    .Select(i=>i.Name)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(name => 
       name + "," + 
       String.Join(",", (from y in list.Select(i=>i.Year).Distinct().OrderBy(y=>y)
                        join item in list.Where(i=>i.Name == name) 
                        on y equals item.Year into outer
                    from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select ((o == null) ? "0" : o.Value.ToString()) 
                         ).ToArray()));
```

You can see it in action here:
http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=9QASFzOJrECO3SJDdUo93A
Just hit "Run"

Isn't Linq Powerful or what...

Comment: I really wouldn't want to debug that.

Comment: :) Obviously you can break it apart to several statements that would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
var minYear = items.Min(i => i.Year);
var maxYear = items.Max(i => i.Year);

var names = items.Select(i => i.Name).Distinct();

using (TextWriter writer = …)
{
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        writer.Write(name);

        for (int y = minYear; y <= maxYear; y++)
        {
            writer.Write(',');

            var value = items.Where(i => i.Name == name && i.Year == y)
                             .Select(i => i.Value)
                             .SingleOrDefault();

            writer.Write(value);
        }

        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This will unnecessarily walk though the `items` collection many times, though. So if speed of this was important to you, you should probably use one or more dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you for your help... However there is a slight change to the list above. the list may not contain distinct years. some times there may me multiple rows for the same year. for example: Smith 2010 111. in that case the .SingleOrDefault(); will not work. So what do i need to change in order to return multiple values for the same year?

Comment: What would you want to output in such case? Sum of all the values?